# Error when registering a enduser for multi tenancy

Tags: wso2-iot

I'm trying to register a user under a multi tenancy account but I'm getting the following error "An unexpected error occurred at backend server. Please try again"
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSTQF.jpg)

The console out error is

> [2016-06-05 13:56:23,880] xxx@xxxx.com [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSTQF.jpg) [EMM]ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [/mdm-admin] threw exception 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unable to find resource 'user-registration'

O/S Wndows 2012 R2 and Ubuntu
EMM is 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue is identified as a known limitation [1] in EMM 2.0.1. You can use below alternative method to create end users for the tenant domain.

1. Go to Management Console using the (https://:9443/carbon/)
2. Login to Management Console using the credentials of tenant admin
3. Go to 'Main' -> 'Identity' and add end users to the tenant domain

   [1] (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-1425)